# Weighted Graphs on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

after reading the Google Maps API Documentation I couldn't find yet what I am looking for, which is why I am asking here.

Basically I have latitude/longtitude points which I need to plot, and in addition I want to implement lines between them, which are weighted (and directed) according to a certain value.

Is this possible via the Google Maps API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The options you can specify when creating a Polyline includes a `strokeWeight` to specify the width of the line.

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PolylineOptions
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple#try-it-yourself